# Can somebody tell me what type of error is this and how to solve it?(C++ / VS 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmd

```
First-chance exception at 0x010CDDD2 in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.  
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The Programs of c++ were working great but suddenly this happened and now all my c++ programs are giving me this error on execution. CMD window appears but totally blank. Can somebody figure out what it is and how to solve it?

Comment: Your program is attempting to read a value from a `NULL` pointer.  You'll need to attach a debugger and see where exactly this error is occuring

Comment: Post your code, otherwise it's impossible to tell.

Comment: It's not any syntax error! 
All of my programs that were working just fine are giving me this on execution!

Comment: Attach a debugger and get a stack trace.

Comment: If all of your programs are doing it, post a short one as an example.  It is impossible to tell otherwise.

Comment: `#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
 return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the exception settings have been changed in Visual Studio. Go to Debug->Exceptions, uncheck all exceptions and see if it happens again.

Comment: Sorry dude nothing happened!